# Excel 2003 - Match Column A with Column B & Column C to correspond to Column B

Tags: excel, sorting

The title is confusing but here is exactly what I have and what I need to do:

`Column A` has a list of numbers.

`Column B` has the same list of numbers in a completely different order.

`Column C` has a list of numbers that correspond directly with `Column B`.

`Column B` needs to be sorted to match `Column A` and during the same sort, the contents of `Column C` need be moved to stay with `Column B`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Column A and B have the same set of numbers which are not repeated?

Comment: Actually Column B has the same numbers, but also some extras (which will not be needed)

Comment: Why not just delete column A then and sort the whole thing on the new Column A?

Comment: Because I have to import these results into another spreadsheet where I cant really change the order of anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Sort Column A by ascending order
- THEN sort Columns B + C by Column B's ascending order

**Update**

Screenshots here: 
http://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2003/22.2

Comment: Can I even do this in Excel 2003?

Comment: You can but I cant take screenshots on this computer as I'm at work with only 2010. Edited answer to link to screenshots showing how to access the sort options.

Comment: Yeah this should have been more obvious to me...another question now...If Column B had more numbers than Column A how could I filter the results to only show what matches between Column A and Column B?

Comment: Add a column D with the following formula In cell D1 then drag down : =IF(iserror(Match(B1,A:A,0)),"B Not in A","B in A")

You can filter by this formula which checks if each item in B is included at all in A

Answer (score 0):

Try using a custom sort under the sort and filter button. If column A and column B have the same numbers you should be able to sort column B either ascending or decending and then add a second level to sort column A.